# Java Web Maven Project on Tomcat 8 root path. How?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web

I have tried to put my application on the root path of the Apache Tomcat, I mean..

This is what I have now: `http://www.mywebsite.com/myapp`

But I need to get this `http://www.mywebsite.com/`

I already tried a lot of things I found on the web, but nothing worked. I found many ways to do this, but nothing works. What should I do on Apache Tomcat 8? Should I do something on the project? any setting on the `pom.xml` or web.xml?

Answer (score 2):

After Maven build artifact, you have `myapp.war`.

1. Shutdown Tomcat.
2. Put it to `%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps` (for example, in my computer: `C:\tools\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps`)
3. **Change file name `myapp.war` to `ROOT.war`**
4. Start Tomcat.
5. You will have web application at `http://www.mywebsite.com/`